# Каким образом можно подписать файл формата PDF электронной подписью (RSA/ ECDSA) используя ЯП C#?

Tags: c#, pdf, rsa, c#-8.0

Скажите, пожалуйста, какие способы существуют для подписи файла формата PDF электронной подписью (RSA/ ECDSA) используя ЯП C#?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7433074/12888024, https://stackoverflow.com/q/7444586/12888024